# How can I build an eternal machine?

Tags: the-sims-3

1. Do I still need the "bridgeport simbot fix" mod to make simbots in bridgeport if my base game version is 1.24 or it's been fixed by EA already?
2. Do I need to be self-registered as an Inventor to get the opportunity to make the simbot or I just need to get to level 10 inventing skill?
3. Can I send a simbot to work, make him join a career?
4. Can I make a simbot immortal? if yes, how? If no, does he eat ambrosia and get the effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it appears that this is still required.
2. No; the opportunity will arise irrespective of what career you have.
3. Yes; SimBots can work. They are usually very well-suited for an Inventor career, in fact. ;)
4. If you have Generations, the Age Freeze Potion lifetime reward should do the trick nicely.

   If not, Ambrosia should give the desired effect.

   Additionally, it's worth considering NRaas' Story Progression mod; which, besides being a pretty great mod overall, also comes with the option of making SimBots, (and vampires, mummies and ghosts) immortal.